# How to extract random points from a list of polygons in Earth Engine (classification accuracy assessment / "is not a function")?

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, accuracy-assessment

I am working on an accuracy assessment for my classification and want to do this using random sampling of points from a validation part of my training areas. For this I split the training areas into a trainSet and a testSet, the latter used for validation after classification is done. Since my training areas are polygons but I want to sample the classified pixels for accuracy, I want to extract random points from the testSet along with its 'class' (integer) property. The class values of these points I then want to compare to the classified pixels using a confusion matrix and outputting an accuracy score.

So far, I have tried both the `.sample()` and the `.randomPoints()` function on my polygons in the testSet. Every time I run these, I get the error message "feature.geometry(...).randomPoint is not a function".

How can I furthermore set a minimum distance between random points?

```
// I want to extract 20 random points per polygon 
var points = testSet.map(function(feature) {
  // Generate 20 random points within the polygon
  var randomPoints = feature.geometry().randomPoints(20);
  // Add the 'class' property from the feature to each point
  return randomPoints.map(function(point) {
    return point.set('class', feature.get('class'));
  });
});

// Flatten the collection of points from each polygon into a single collection
points = points.flatten();
```

The testSet feature collection should be available here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ee-pcfrandsen/assets/testSet

---

Since I did not get to functionally run the code yet, I would also like to share the follow-up code that tries to compare the point 'class' value to the pixel 'class' values of the image. Does this look functional?

```
// Function to get class and pixel values
function getValues(point) {
  var pointCoord = ee.Feature(point).geometry().coordinates();
  var pixelValue = image.sample(pointCoord);
  return ee.List([point.get('class'), pixelValue]);
}

// Map function to extract values and create confusion matrix
var confusionMatrix = points.map(getValues).reduce(ee.Reducer.confusionMatrix({
  'classes': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  'reducer': ee.Reducer.countNonEmpty()
}));
```

EDIT:
When importing a number of points and using the code above for comparison, it outputs the error "ee.Reducer.countNonEmpty is not a function" again and when deleting that line it finds the error somewhere else "ee.Reducer.confusionMatrix is not a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to generate this random points using this code block:

```
Map.addLayer(testSet);
print(testSet);

// Creates a collection of random points in/near each polygon in a collection.
function makePoints(site){
  // var center = site.geometry().centroid();  //if one centroid is needed
  var siteP = site.geometry();
  var point = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(siteP, 20);
  var feature = ee.Feature(point.geometry());
  // copy properties from the parent polygon feature
  feature = feature.copyProperties(site);
  return feature;
}

var points = testSet.map(makePoints);
print(points);
Map.addLayer(points);


// Rest of the code block
```

`.sample` is for the image type, so `.randomPoints()` should be the way to generate 20 points within the polygon.

As for the minimum distance between each random points, I don't think there is any mechanism inbuilt in EE complimenting the .randomPoints() function. You might have to add additional functions that explicitly checks the distance between points, probably by drawing a buffer and checking number of points contained within that buffer, and try to eliminate other points. (I don't have code for that), but the above should solve the issue with generating random points.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This code manages to generate the random points containing the property of each polygon! Unfortunately, the second bit of code still has the same issues as earlier.